# Rails eager loading with customized query

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, eager-loading

I am building an RSS reader which has the following model:

```
class Folder < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :user_id, :is_expanded

  has_many :feeds
end

class Feed < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :last_checked_date, :url, :name, :folder_id

  has_many :items
  has_many :subscriptions
end

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :description, :feed_id, :publication_date, :title, :url, :guid

  belongs_to :feed
  has_many :item_to_reads
end

class ItemToRead < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_table_name "items_to_read"

  attr_accessible :item_id, :user_id

  belongs_to :item
end
```

So I have a list of folders, which contain feeds, which can in turn contain a list of items. For a given user, I would like to show `items_to_read` only for each feed.

I can't find any way to make a request which:

- retrieves a list of folders and inner feeds for a given user
- shows a count of `items_to_read` for each feed
- if possible also computes a sum of `items_to_read` for each folder (sum of the `items_to_read` of each sub-feed)

Point 3 could be done later (outside of the request).

Retrieving folders and feeds is easy:

```
Folder.includes(:feeds).where(:user_id => user_id)
```

But I can't customize the second query which retrieves the feeds:

```
>> Folder.includes(:feeds).where(:user_id => 1)
  Folder Load (0.9ms)  SELECT "folders".* FROM "folders" WHERE "folders"."user_id" = 1
  Feed Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "feeds".* FROM "feeds" WHERE "feeds"."folder_id" IN ('8')
```

Using `:finder_sql` in `has_many :feeds` does not fit my problem, it won't be used in `includes`.

What are my options? Should I do the counts in another query?

---

**EDIT:**
I found a separate query that retrieves only the number of `items_to_read` per feed:

```
Feed.group('feeds.id').joins(:items => :item_to_reads).where('items_to_read.user_id' => user_id).count('items_to_read.id')
```

Can this be merged with my first query?